# for a browser to initiate HTTP/2 download of assets, does the initial page load need to be HTTP/2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, http2

We have our (PHP/Magento2) site hosted on AWS using ELB and Cloudfront. Due to a limitation in ELB, the initial HTML response is HTTP/1.1 however we've configured the static assets (JS, CSS, images) to be served over HTTP/2 via Cloudfront. We are concerned however that the browser doesn't know that it should use HTTP/2 for those downstream assets and so it doesn't. There are ~300 requests on the page that could be accelerated if the browser uses HTTP/2. Note that Require.JS is in use for the 100-odd JS files, so the Require.JS initiator itself is loaded over HTTP/2...

Is it a requirement for the initial response to be HTTP/2 in order for the browser to use HTTP/2 for the subsequent requests?

Comment: Are the assets on a different domain/subdomain, or is the entire site, including the ELB (Classic?) behind CloudFront?  It doesn't actually change the substance of the answer, but some details will differ and I'd like to understand your setup correctly.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot the assets that are served from CloudFront are on a different (sub-)domain.